# C# Groupby Distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database table (called Info) that stores [Data], [fkID], [UserID], [Timestamp].  [Data] is actually multiple columns, but it doesn't really matter.

Essentially a user can go and input data into a form, and the form inserts a new row into Info.

What I want to be able to do is select the most recent [Data] item from each [UserID] for a specific [fkID].  This can be done in LINQ, I just haven't figured it out.  Here is what I have so far:

```
var q = (from i in db.Info
        where i.fkID == @paramID
        orderby Timestamp descending
        groupby new {i.UserID})
        .Distinct()
```

This obviously doesn't work. It returns the correct UserID but not the [Data] part that I actually want.

In words, here is what I want to do:

For each entry in Info with a certain fkID, I want to select the most recent row from each User.

I'd like to know how to do this in LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the first row in each group, like this:

```
var q = from i in db.Info
        where i.fkID == @paramID
        group i by i.UserID into g
        select new { 
            UserID = g.Key, 
            Recent = g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Timestamp).First() 
        };
```

Comment: This looks right.  I haven't tested it yet, but I assume it works.  When I do test it, I'll mark yours correct.  THanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.First()` instead of `.Distinct()`